# Restoring SQL Server database to another SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server

If I have a SQL Server database backup, in order to restore it to another SQL Server instance, do I need to provide any password?

I tried restoring it but it didn't asked for a password to restore?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Have you tried researching the web on this subject? Can you share what you found so far

Comment: Did the restore fail? I feel like we're missing the other half of the story here. And you might get better response on the dba.stackexchange site

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=do+i+need+a+password+to+restore+database+sql+server

Comment: I found following SQL to backup the DB with password but "MEDIAPASSWOED" key word is not recognizing by SQL as a key word               
                                                                                                              
 (BACKUP DATABASE Northwind TO DISK='C:\Northwind.BAK' WITH MEDIAPASSWORD='mssqltips')

Comment: From what i researched i got to know that you don't need a password to restore the DB to another server instance

Comment: Duplicate of and answered in [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6208e58-a9b0-42bf-8972-bdcd882e768b/restoring-sql-server-database-to-another-sql-server-instance?forum=sqlgetstarted). Posting the same question to multiple forums is a waste of time/effort of others who don't know that you have duplicated your post.

Comment: Yah but stil i did not got a proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a SQL Server database backup, in order to restore it to
>   another SQL Server instance, do I need to provide any password?

No, you do not need.

Older versions (before SQL Server 2012) had an option `MEDIAPASSWORD`

However it was retired in newer releases, therefore password protected backups cannot be created anymore on SQL Server 2012 and higher

At the same time  old password-protected backups still can be restored using t-sql, an 
example:

```
RESTORE DATABASE YourDB FROM DISK='C:\Temp\YourDB.BAK' WITH MEDIAPASSWORD='secretPassword'
```

In modern versions of SQL Server backups can be protected more serious way using `Backup Encryption`

References:

- [Backup Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-encryption?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Using passwords with SQL Server database backup files](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1108/using-passwords-with-sql-server-database-backup-files/)

Comment: Thank you, this was really healpfull